# How to serialize specific Json object from C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, datatable

I have a requirement where i need to serialize `json` object in below format

```
[{
    "columns": [{
        "title": "NAME"
    }, {
        "title": "COUNTY"
    }],
    "data": [
        ["John Doe", "Fresno"],
        ["Billy", "Fresno"],
        ["Tom", "Kern"],
        ["King Smith", "Kings"]
    ]
}]
```

Here i need to get this json object from two different source, one is `Columns` and other is `data`. Columns would come from a `string` which will be comma separated as

```
string columnNames = "Name, County";
```

and `data` would come from .net Datatable like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

I tried with below code using `JavaScriptSerializer` but i am not able to format it in the required format. Actually, shared format is required to dynamically create jquery datatable. Here is my raw code in C#.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ConvertDatadttoString(string appName)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("County", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add("vo", "go.com");
    dt.Rows.Add("pa", "pa.com");

    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

Above code is only serializing the `DataTable` and is not able to create in the required format. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your code outputting? How does it differ from what you were aiming for?

Comment: Use json2csharp.com to figure out what your model should look like. Use JSON.NET to serialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do, is I build a model based off of the data, and serialize that model.

This is how I'd imagine your model would look.

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public IEnumerable<SampleItem> columns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> data { get; set; }
}

public class SampleItem
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I'd imagine you'd get the sample json

```
var sample = new List<SampleClass>
{
    new SampleClass()
    {
        columns = new List<SampleItem>()
        {
            new SampleItem() {title = "NAME" },
            new SampleItem() {title = "COUNTY" },
        },
        data = new List<List<string>>()
        {
            new List<string> { "John Doe", "Fresno" },
            new List<string> { "Billy", "Fresno" },
            new List<string> { "Tom", "Kern" },
            new List<string> { "King Smith", "Kings" },
        }
    }
};

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(sample);
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to create that model based off of your real data.  It's not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to create a class, but if you want to work with a `Dictionary<string,object>` then you need to first add an entry for your columns:

```
rows["columns"] = dt.Columns.Cast<DataTableColumn>()
                            .Select(c => new { title = c.ColumnName }).ToList();
```

And then you can add your data with something like:

```
rows["data"] = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>.Select(r => r.ItemArray).ToList();
```

Now you have a `Dictionary<string,object>` with two items `columns` and `rows`. `columns` contains a collection of objects with a property `title` and `rows` just contains an array of arrays for each row.

But this is a quick and dirty solution. I think creating a class as per @Sam I am's answer is cleaner and easier to maintain in the long run.

If you are starting with a comma separated list of column names, it really shouldn't be much harder to do. Something like:

```
var columns = columnNames.Split(",");    // beware of column names that include commas!

row["columns"] = columns.Select(c => new { title = c });

row["data"] = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>.Select(r => columns.Select(c => r[c]).ToList());
```

Comment: Could you please guide me on adding the column names from string which is separated with comma as shared in the post. Datatable should give only rows, Column names need to be custom and User specific rather than database table name

Comment: @Lara: It shouldn't be hard to `Split` your string and pick out the column names. Then for your rows you just have to be sure to only take the values you need.

Comment: Tried to implement the shared code as of now but getting error at `columns.Select(c => new { title: c });` do i need to define `title` somewhere ?

Comment: `the name title does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @Lara: Sorry, my bad. I always get javascript and C# mixed up with annoymous types. It should be `title = c`.

Comment: I tried to implement but getting error as `Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.` at line `dt.Rows.Add("vo", "go.com");'` I have updated my post with the code that i added as per your answer.Pls have a look.Thanks

Comment: @Lara: That would be a question about populating an datatable and nothing to do with serialization. If you have another question, ask another question. In your update you never added any columns to your datatable - hence the error.